# Username Not Displayed as Sender and Not Saved to Database Column in Socket.IO Chat Application

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, openai-api

https://github.com/WILLIAMSTAMP/usernameNotSavingToDB

Description:
I'm facing an issue with my Socket.IO chat application where the username is not being displayed as the sender in the console logs, and it is also not being saved to the database in the appropriate sender column. I'm seeking support from the developer community to help me troubleshoot and resolve this problem.

Here's an overview of the relevant parts of my application:

1. User Authentication: I'm using Passport.js with a LocalStrategy for user authentication. After successful login, the username is stored in the session.
2. Socket.IO Setup: I have set up Socket.IO for real-time communication between the server and the client.
3. Message Handling: When a user sends a chat message, an event named 'chat' is emitted from the client to the server.
4. Server-Side Processing: On the server side, I have an event listener for the 'chat' event. Inside this event listener, I try to retrieve the username associated with the socket ID and use it as the sender of the message.
5. Database Interaction: I'm using the MySQL database to store chat messages. When a message is received, I attempt to save it to the database along with the sender's username.

The issue I'm facing is that the username is not being displayed in the console logs as the sender when a message is received. Additionally, when the message is saved to the database, the sender column does not contain the correct username; instead, it appears to be empty or undefined.

I have performed the following steps to debug the issue:

1. Verified that the username is successfully stored in the session after user login.
2. Confirmed that the socket ID is correctly associated with the username when a user connects to the server.
3. Checked the event flow and ensured that the 'chat' event is properly triggered and received on the server side.
4. Inspected the session object and socket object to ensure that the username is accessible within the event listener.
5. Verified that the database connection is established and functioning correctly.
6. Examined the database query and ensured that the username parameter is passed correctly.

Despite these efforts, I have been unable to identify the cause of the issue. I suspect it might be related to asynchronous execution or incorrect usage of session and socket objects.

I kindly request assistance from the developer community to help me troubleshoot and resolve this problem. Any insights, suggestions, or code snippets that can shed light on why the username is not displayed correctly in the console logs and not saved to the sender column in the database would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your time and support!